# Posting a link to chat.mse (or chat.se or chat.so) in chat gives unexpected results

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

Whenever you post https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/ on a line on its own in chat, it will open to the logo of Meta Stack Exchange and link to https://meta.stackexchange.com/ instead. (Effectively behaving like a link to https://meta.stackexchange.com/ on a line of its own).

The same behavior is displayed for https://chat.stackexchange.com/ and https://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Same happens when you post http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ it just links to Stack Overflow: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2150335#2150335